# Need Help understanding how PATH works with Windows 7

Tags: path, windows-7

I am trying to add to the PATH via the Environment Variable settings windows for python.exe.
I have read the instructions using SetX from the March 3, 2012 discussion about this issue and am worried I will make a mess of my machine, so want to stick with the GUI process.

The directory path is C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe.
That is a copy from the addition I made in the System Variables section of the Environment Variables window.
I have labelled the Variable Name as "Python", no quotation marks.

I have checked the path, and it looks good to me, and have rebooted the computer. But I still get the
'python.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.' error in every directory expect if I am specifically in the Python37 directory.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The path environment variable contains one or more paths, separated by semicolons. When you try to execute a command in cmd.exe it checks each path listed in the path variable in order of first to last until it finds the executable or runs out of paths to check.

You can experiment without making permanent changes to your system first. Run cmd.exe and type

```
set path=%path%;C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
```

Running python.exe should now work in any directory in this cmd.exe window.

Unlike other environment variables, path is special and is a merged value from the system and user variables. Since you installed python just for yourself you might as well just use a user variable.

In the system properties where you edit environment variables, if there is no path user variable, create one and set it to `C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37` or if it already exists, append `;C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37`.

In newer versions of Windows 10 the UI is different and you don't have to add the semicolon because it lets you edit them as separate entries.